# armazenar resultado do select em uma tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server

Boa tarde

Eu possuo a seguinte query

```
SELECT
 +cast((DATEDIFF(SECOND,r.start_time,GETDATE())/60)%60 as varchar)+'m '
 duracao
 ,isnull(s.login_name, s.original_login_name) AS LOGIN
 ,r.session_id
 ,r.wait_time
 ,r.cpu_time
 --,r.total_elapsed_time
 --,r.logical_reads
-- ,r.row_count
 --,r.blocking_session_id
 --,r.wait_resource
-- ,pp.lastwaittype
-- ,pp.status
 ,sql.TEXT
 FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r
 JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions s ON s.session_id = r.session_id
 OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) sql
 OUTER apply (select max(p.lastwaittype) as lastwaittype, min(p.status) as status  from sys.sysprocesses p where p.spid = r.session_id ) pp
 WHERE 1 = 1
  and r.database_id NOT IN (1,0)
  AND cast((DATEDIFF(SECOND,r.start_time,GETDATE())/60)%60 as varchar) > 10
  order by 1 desc
```

E uma tabela chamada coleta_query, eu gostaria de armazenar o resultado dessa consulta na minha tabela, alguém saberia?

Comment: A tabela ``coleta_query`` possui as mesmas colunas que o resultado da consulta?

Comment: INSERT INTO sua_tabela (sua_lista_de campos) seu_comando_select

Comment: Qual o sentido de você colocar em sua cláusula WHERE 1 = 1  and ? Será possível que tal cláusula dê resultado falso?

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução simples é encapsular o código SQL da consulta em uma expressão de tabela comum (CTE, *common table expression*) e utilizar a instrução INSERT para incluir o resultado da consulta na tabela `coleta_query`.

```
-- código #1
with Consulta as (
SELECT ...
  from ...
  where ...
)
INSERT into coleta_query (duracao, login, session_id, wait_time, cpu_time, [text])
  SELECT duracao, login, session_id, wait_time, cpu_time, [text]
    from Consulta;
```

Retire a cláusula ORDER BY do código original de sua consulta.

Informe os nomes das colunas da tabela coleta_query na instrução INSERT; para demonstração eu utilizei os mesmos nomes da consulta SQL original.